# Animating an ImageView slows down other animations

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am using this [library](https://github.com/gpfduoduo/RadarScanView/) for an Radar Scan view. This is the [class](https://github.com/gpfduoduo/RadarScanView/blob/master/RadarScanView/library/src/main/java/com/guo/duoduo/library/RadarScanView.java) which I am using to achieve the radar view.

Now I am trying to popup an `ImageView` in my Activity. .

This is the code I a using.

```
animation.XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

And this is how I am setting the Animation

```
  Animation expandIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.animation);
    expandIn.setRepeatCount(0);
    expandIn.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    img1.startAnimation(expandIn);
```

Now the problem is that I call the animation code every 4 seconds. Whenever the Animation code is called the rotation of the radar becomes slow and when the ImageView disappears again the rotation is back to normal.

Can anyone help me solve this error.

Comment: OMG they are calling `new SweepGradient` inside `onDraw` method...

Comment: @pskink Thanks. But since I am new I am not sure of the effect of calling `new SweepGradient`  inside `onDraw`. Can you please explain whether is it really something wrong.

Comment: do you see that `new SweepGradiend(...` is underscored with yellow (warning) line? if you move your mouse over that line the tooltip will appear explaining everything

Comment: @pskink Thanks again. I have created a Global Variable and then checking in `onDraw` if the `Shader` is null or not . And only if it is null I am calling the `new SweepGradiend`.